# I am getting Unexpected end of the file. Only occurs on prod server. Working fine in dev servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml-parsing

Here is my error details.

```
[2022-12-08T15:26:46.1761002Z] Unexpected end of file.
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ReadBOMEncoding(Boolean notOutOfBand)
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at DMS.BusinessLogic.ApiHelper.Deserialize(String xml, Type toType) in d:\InmarsatSourceCode\CRMA-DMS\DMSSourceCode\Sources\DMS.BusinessLogic\DMS.BusinessLogic\APIHelper.cs:line 299
```

The code of the trace that gives me error is below

```
 public object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
                return deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }
```

I wonder why the same code working totally fine on dev servers and my local code connected to prod server. But if we login to prod server everything messes up.Please suggest.

We have tried re starting the production servers. Tried to analyse data. But went futile.

The latest finding is the server is returning with error 500 and for every 500 server error I am getting the above message in the UI. I am connecting the same server from visual studio and I am getting a successful response. Is this having anything to do with IIS. But both local IIS and production IIS are up and running. I have restrated the app pools for the same.Any other IIS or server dependencies to verify?

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of the XML you are trying to deserialize, and the EOL (end of line) characters. From what I see, the error occurs in `System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ReadBOMEncoding`. So I believe it has something to do with BOM (byte order mark) in UTF.